# Events being published through Open Graph not showing on newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am successfully publishing events via the Open Graph APIs and can verify the entries show up on my Activity Feed. However, these events are not showing up on the newsfeed. They will not show up for the user I'm posting from, nor friends of the user (who are administrators of the application) as well. If I go to http://www.facebook.com/myuser/activity/id_returned_from_post, the entry is there. Why would it not show up in the newsfeed?

Comment: This looks like a bug: [Creation of public events not retrievable using FQL from the stream table](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/345921902137902) Subscribe to it if you able to reproduce it by outlined steps, or file a new one otherwise...